# How to create a spacing before a title in Bulma, without using a content container

Tags: css, stylesheet, bulma

I want to create a simple html page by using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) as stylesheet. My expectation is, that there is a reasonable default spacing when using headlines and text. Expecially I am expecting a spacing between a paragraph and the next headline. The [documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/content/) is saying

> When you can't use the CSS classes you want, or when you just want to
>   directly use HTML tags, use `content` as container.

With a content container `<div class="content">...</div>` then the spacing is satisfying. But my understanding is that `content` container is optional and that I can achieve the same without a content container. But with the following example there is no space between first paragraph and second headline. What is the best practice to create such a spacing without content container?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My first Bulma website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <h3 class="title is-4">First title</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo. 
          </p>
          <h3 class="title is-4">Second title - with no spacing to previous paragraph</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Rendered result in firefox:

[image]

Comment: This issue is touching the same topic: https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2019

Comment: Just add margin-bottom to the paragraph...No?

Comment: I was hoping there is some concept in bulma which I missed, and which would enable reasonable behaviour of default classes, but maybe I need to accept that it is either a bug in bulma or in my pov a weak concept. I wait some time then I'll accept the answer of @Jonny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use HTML < br > tags for a line break.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My first Bulma website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <h3 class="title is-4">First title</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo. 
          </p><br><br>
          <h3 class="title is-4">Second title - with no spacing to previous paragraph</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Jonny, thank you for the answer. I wonder if this is the intended method or best practice, or just a workaround.

Comment: Using the < br > tag in HTML seems to be the simplest and most logical way to do this without creating new styles, or over riding the style sheet with additional styles with !important attached to them. Though there are several ways to do the same thing in coding The < br > tag is standard HTML and is not a bad practice to use it for a line break that's what it is intended for. Adding additional styles or over riding original styles can have the same effect.  Its just a matter of preference.  Just makes sense to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class called 'intexttitle' with a top margin of 1rem. This new class is added to your own stylesheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My first Bulma website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <h3 class="title is-4">First title</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo. 
          </p>
          <h3 class="intexttitle is-4">Second title - with no spacing to previous paragraph</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate ornare mollis. Donec in vulputate
            urna, id vestibulum lacus. Suspendisse vestibulum ipsum at mollis auctor. Ut finibus mi sed pharetra
            finibus. Suspendisse id felis dui. Nullam sit amet felis vel elit malesuada tristique at eu eros. Maecenas
            sit amet massa tellus. Quisque eleifend purus semper nibh tincidunt commodo.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```